# duplicates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, epicorerp

I'm trying to create a SQL query for an inventory report.  I have thus far created a SQL query that successfully brings back unique part numbers along with their description and Quantity on Hand.  I would like to add the customer name to my report but since we sell some parts to multiple customers, adding this causes duplicates in part numbers and Quantities on hand, despite the DISTINCT statement.  Is there a way to limit results to only one customer listed per part?  I am new to SQL so I imagine I am missing something obvious.  Here is my query:

[SQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA8lU.png)

```
select distinct [Part].[PartNum] as [Part_PartNum]
    , [Part].[PartDescription] as [Part_PartDescription]
    , [PartBin].[OnhandQty] as [PartBin_OnhandQty] 
from Erp.Part as Part 
inner join Erp.ShipDtl as ShipDtl on Part.Company = ShipDtl.Company 
                            And Part.PartNum = ShipDtl.PartNum 
inner join Erp.PartBin as PartBin on Part.Company = PartBin.Company 
                            And Part.PartNum = PartBin.PartNum 
order by Part.PartNum
```

Comment: Add queries as Text not as link to an image

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result as well. (As well formatted text.)

Comment: select distinct
 [Part].[PartNum] as [Part_PartNum],
 [Part].[PartDescription] as [Part_PartDescription],
 [PartBin].[OnhandQty] as [PartBin_OnhandQty]
from Erp.Part as Part
inner join Erp.ShipDtl as ShipDtl on 
 Part.Company = ShipDtl.Company
And
 Part.PartNum = ShipDtl.PartNum

inner join Erp.PartBin as PartBin on 
 Part.Company = PartBin.Company
And
 Part.PartNum = PartBin.PartNum
 order by  Part.PartNum

Comment: You should edit the question with your query. Comments are horrible for formatting. I will format this and add it for you.

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of using an alias. When you alias a table with the exact name as the table name it provides no benefit and just causes you to type more. Either use an alias that is a different name or don't bother. As for the actual question at hand we need some details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Why are you joining table ShipDtl? You are only reporting records from Part and PartBin so you won't need that table. Could it be that multiple customers are bound to a single part?

Comment: @SeanLange you are correct, but the ERP system she's using doesn't allow for the creation of custom aliases; the system simply takes the table name and assigns it as the alias.

Comment: @user2572833 that is a really stupid decision by the creator of that ERP. That is like saying my name is Sean (aka Sean). Some of the decisions made in ERPs are truly mind boggling.

Comment: Thank you for the info on posting format.  I'm new at this.  I will reformat with these guidelines in mind.

Comment: Essentially it seems like you are trying to get the query to omit data which matches your criteria. Assuming that I've understood that correctly, if you only want to show one customer per item, does it matter which customer where there is more than one?

Comment: Although it sounds somewhat counter-intuitive, I only need to list one customer/part, and it does not matter which customer for parts with multiple buyers.

Comment: Okay, and just to check the tables ... the joins suggest that the "Part" table has multiple entries for the same part number (one per customer) but they have the same part number. Is the quantity on hand then really "on hand for that customer" or is it meant to be the sum of the on hand across the multiple rows?

Comment: The quantity on hand is the total inventory on hand for that given part.  When I bring in customer names, I see that total value duplicated for each unique customer who buys it.

Comment: I am most concerned that the part numbers and quantity on hand are only listed once, for inventory audit.  However, management would, at a glance, like to see a customer name as well.  For most of our parts this is only one customer, but like I said, I have some duplicates.

Comment: @user2572833 Epicor ERP does allow the aliases as shown in the query, but as Sean says they are not necessary. `SELECT TOP 1 Part.PartNum FROM Erp.Part` would also work just fine.

Comment: @webturner Yes, but she doesn't define them; the system does. She's using the BAQ tool, which creates all query code as defined by the system logic. There's no way for her to change these aliases to something that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Epicor, I see...

Is there a reason you're joining the ShipDtl table, since your select statement is only pulling back information from the Part and PartBin tables? Try the following:

```
SELECT p.PartNum, PartDescription, OnHandQty
FROM erp.Part AS Part INNER JOIN
     erp.PartBin AS PartBin ON Part.Company = PartBin.Company and Part.PartNum = PartBin.PartNum
```

Please note also that if your company uses multiple bins, you will have to do a summation on the OnHandQty field in order to get the total for that company, which will also require a group by statement.

Comment: I originally included shipdtl in the query, as I was trying to pull in the Customer name as well.  However, when I pull the customer table in, I am getting duplicate rows, due to some parts being sold to multiple customers.

Comment: @AliceElizabeth Maybe I am misunderstanding, but your query doesn't quite make sense to me. You're trying to pull back information from the PartBin table, which stores inventory information, yet you want to pull the customer from the ShipDtl table, which holds shipping transactions. It seems that you're trying to pull back information that isn't directly related. In order to have a part make its way through to the ShipDtl table, you have to cut a PO against it. The PartBin table splits out your inventory based on location, not by selling information. I think you're trying to merge two reports.

Comment: Wow, I see that this was not an effective way to bring "Customer" name into my report.  I need to regroup and find a better way bring in this customer information.  Thank you for that.

Comment: @AliceElizabeth It's no problem. Just note that multiple customers can purchase the same part and that the onhandqty is counted on a per-bin basis, not per part or shipment. I can mull this over a bit and try to come up with a solution. If my answer was helpful, feel free to up-vote :)

Comment: @AliceElizabeth I may have a solution for you, but it's probably too complex for the query builder to handle. Do you have access to SSRS? If so, you could run a base report off of the part and part bin tables, then format a subreport using the shipdtl table to show all customers who purchased that part.

Comment: Is this something I could accomplish in Report Builder or do I need to work in Visual Studio?  I recently tried to modify a .rdl report in Visual Studio to eliminate whitespace and when I uploaded it back to my report server, there was an incompatibility issue.  I do see how your suggestion could be a viable solution.  I will have to explore.

Comment: @AliceElizabeth You should be able to. I'm not as familiar with Report Builder since I do all report writing through Visual Studio, but their capabilities are very similar. Sorry I don't have a more definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following might work. It uses a subquery to identify a relevant single company for the part in question.

I've assumed there is also another table "Company" where you might want to pull some company details from rather than simply the "Company" field on which you are joining. You'll see that I've just taken the "minimum" Company to be the one to return. There are other ways to do the same thing. You could instead take the minimum (or maximum or somethings else) company from the "Part" table instead. Let me know how you get on.

```
select
    [Part].[PartNum] as [Part_PartNum]
    , [Part].[PartDescription] as [Part_PartDescription]
    , [Company].[CompanyDesc] as [CompanyDesc]
    , [PartBin].[OnhandQty] as [PartBin_OnhandQty] 
from
    Erp.Part as Part 
    inner join
    (
     select
        ShipDtl.PartNum,
        min(ShipDtl.Company) Company
     from
        Erp.ShipDtl
     group by
        ShipDtl.PartNum
    ) as Part1Company ON
        Part.Company = Part1Company.Company AND
        Part.PartNum = Part1Company.PartNum
    inner join Erp.PartBin as PartBin on
        Part.Company = PartBin.Company And
        Part.PartNum = PartBin.PartNum 
    inner join Erp.Company as Company on
        Part.Company = Company.Company
order by
    Part.PartNum
```

Comment: Thank you, this was useful to understand how to use the Min/Max to my advantage.  I think with a little adjustment I can make it work.  Alas, I can't up-vote since I'm a newbie, but I've gotten a lot of valuable info.

Comment: No worries Alice. Hopefully between my response and that of user2572833, you've got the makings of a solution.